# How do I turn a list into multiple return values?

Tags: scheme, racket

Suppose I have a list, but I want to convert it into `values`. For example:

```
(define (f mylist)
  (values ...))  ; <- What do I write here?
```

If I call `(f '(1 2 3))`, I would like to get the same result as `(values 1 2 3)`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `apply`:

```
(define (f mylist)
  (apply values mylist))
```

You'll get the desired result:

```
(f '(1 2 3))
=> 1
   2
   3
```